# Etymological questions on philosophy.stackexchange -- suitable?

Tags: discussion

Ah yeah this is [*an idea*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297523/is-there-an-etymology-stack-exchange).

Or are they suitable, here, on philosophy.stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etymology proper is clearly the domain of the English Language SE's.  But we tend to answer questions about meanings of things that actually appear in the context of philosophy and may be affected by etymological concerns.

Comment: tend to agree, yes. however, i don't think the english.stackexchange is necessarily good for it, as yet anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an etymology site

> was proposed, but it did not go anywhere and got deleted.

Unfortunately, I lack the charisma, to try, again. I suppose we can ask the etymology of philosophical terms, like e.g. [nominalism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nominalism#Etymology), here, as I think the answers on philosophy.stack would be far more illuminating.